# How to construct a 2-player normal form game with exactly n Nash equilibria?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Just like the title, how to construct a 2-player normal form game with exactly n Nash equilibria?

Construct a NxN game with N pure NEs or we could also construct a 2x2 game with as many NEs as we want?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to construct an $N\times N$ game with $N$ pure strategy Nash Equilibria is to make one of the players have $N-1$ strictly dominated strategies and make the other player completely indifferent.

For the $2 \times 2$ question, in pure strategies, a priori we can have 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 pure strategy Nash Equilibria. We can have examples for all of these

0: matching pennies

1: Prisoner's Dilemma

2: Battle of the Sexes

3:$$\begin{array}{r | c | c |}& L & R \\ \hline T & 1,1 & 1,1 \\ \hline B & 1,1 & 0,0\end{array}$$

4: Nihilistic game where nothing matters